# IK show bones Degrees of Freedom

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, inverse-kinematics

I rigged a human and now want to set the limits. I have a blue / red ring that visualizes the limits on the x and z axis but not on the y axis ( I just found out that I can deactivate them by unchecking "relationship lines")

I only found this visualization of limits:
https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_Dokumentation:_Constraint:_IK_Solver#/media/File:Blender3D_IK_chain_limit.jpg
But I cant find the option to activate this in 2.78.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show this you need to go under the Bone properties tab and then Under the Inverse Kinematics you can set the rotation limits of the bones as shown below:

[image]

Note: Only X and Z limits will be represented in the 3d view as rotation around Y is rolling the bone around it's axis so it can't be visualised

Comment: Thanks that worked! Can I set the maximum limit to a negative value? Because I want to limit it from -180 ° to -170° on the y axis and it wont let me set the max to -170° or + 190°

Comment: @AlexanderWeller I recommend asking another separate question for this.